# Can't use the computer - all input I type is repeated

Tags: candy-box-2

For some reason when I try and use the developer's computer to make cheats it also gets triple the input. So hhh instead of just h. completely unusable. I'm using firefox and tried it in internet explorer but that still gets 2 inputs. Gah I'm going crazy.

Comment: What about Chrome? Opera? Safari?

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137385), though a duplicate of this one, has better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Reload your browser. Did the same to me...