# The Computer is broken - repeating characters

Tags: candy-box-2

When I go to The Computer, any key I press comes out as six copies of that key. When I type `test` it comes out as `tttttteeeeeesssssstttttt`. Someone else had a similar problem, with all letters coming out doubled.

Comment: Yeah, same here. Using newest chrome

Comment: You can answer your own question if you find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug when loading your save with text load. Each time I load the same text string I get an extra character typed in.

What you can do is to use the text load, then save to a slot and then load from that slot. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, reload the page (**having saved**) and it seems to fix itself.